# How to use multiple upload image in ckeditor image2 plugin?

Tags: javascript, image, laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is it some configuration rule for multiple upload image in CKEditor image2 plugin? My current configuration is:

```
editor.ckeditor({
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    extraPlugins: 'embed,autoembed,image2',
    image2_alignClasses: [ 'image-align-left', 'image-align-center','image-align-right' ],
    image2_disableResizer: true,
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=' + editor.attr('data-token'),
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token=' + editor.attr('data-token')
});
```

Comment: You can integrate CKFinder on CKEditor for uploading files/images and CKFinder have a lot of plugins for multiple uploads, you can check there: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration

Comment: I use laravel-filemanager for this case and it is work perfectly, but my customer need to upload multiple images directly in CKEditor area

Comment: I don't now why my question receive so many down-votes? ... tell please what is wrong and in future I will avoid this mistakes

Comment: You need to explain better your problem and give more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plugin that provides multiple image uploading using ckeditor. It doesn't appear that ckeditor itself supports multiple image uploading.

https://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/simpleuploads.demo4/

Comment: Thanks for help, but it is commercial plugin :(