# Insert Multi image by using CK editor with Roxy File manager

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I'm Using CK Editor And Foxy file manager to manager file: Image, file, etc.
Here is link demo:http://www.roxyfileman.com/demo
Current i can insert 1 image at 1 time only. I want to select multiple images

Any suggest.
Thank you all.

Comment: Please post your code you used to get this far asking for help. Post also error code where possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587321/how-to-use-multiple-upload-image-in-ckeditor-image2-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin that provides multiple image uploading using ckeditor. It doesn't appear that ckeditor itself supports multiple image uploading.

https://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/simpleuploads.demo4/

see : [How to use multiple upload image in ckeditor image2 plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587321/how-to-use-multiple-upload-image-in-ckeditor-image2-plugin)

Comment: You saved my life.
Ill try it.
Thank you.

Comment: @NguyễnQuốcThịnh if this answer has helped you, don't hesitate to upvote it. If it has answered your question, you could even accept it. :)